# How to cloud 4 VPS with cPanel ?

Tags: cloud, cpanel, cloud-hosting

I have 4 Dedicated server From 4 different country, also I have WHM/cPanel Hosting on Cloudlinux VPS.

Can I make 4 VPS on these Servers and Cloud theme to use for cPanel Hosting? And How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a cloud server at the first.

Using  [OpenStack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack) (free and open-source software cloud computing platform)

After that you can install cloud Linux on the clouded server.

CloudLinux is not a cloud solution, it's just a way to make virtual host host on a server.